# Is $F=\{-1, 0, 1\}$ a subfield of $\mathbb C$?

Tags: field-theory

Is $F=\{-1, 0, 1\}$ a subfield of $\mathbb C$?

I have just started reading Linear Algebra text by Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze.
They wrote that "any subfield of $\mathbb C$ must contain every rational number", this statement implies that $F$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb C$ even though the operations of addition and multiplication on $F$ are defined in $F$.

Am I overlooking some fact?

Comment: What's $1+1$? ${}{}$

Comment: Then how is addition defined in $\{-1,0,1\}\subseteq \mathbb C$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$F$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$; it is not closed under addition.

Example: $1+1=2\notin F$. Although $1$ is an element of $F$, $2$ is not.

Comment: If we were to adhere to the common usage of the phrase, the point is that addition and multiplication aren't *defined on* $F$, for the reason you've said.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path thank you for pointing that out, I've corrected it.